# Нужна ли строка .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR) перед публикацией в Google Play?

Tags: android, admob

Нужно/можно или нельзя убирать строку `.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)` перед публикацией приложения в Google Play Маркет?

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не очень понятно почему это вас интересует, но ответ - можно и не обязательно. В принципе можно сделать так - добавлять тестовые девайсы только для нерелизных версий. Вот так:

```
AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    builder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);
}
builder.build();
```